# Compute $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{x^n}{z^n}}{n\beta + \alpha}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Known that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^n}{z^n}=\frac{1}{1-xz}$.  If we have   $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{x^n}{z^n}}{n\beta + \alpha}$ where $\beta, \alpha $ are element of real numbers but not equal $0$. What is a suitable expression for that summation?

Comment: This question is not very clear-at least to me.

Comment: Why you don't just replace $xz$ by (say) $t$ so that the question is simpler? (this does not answer it, mind you).

Comment: Do you know the answer when $\alpha = 0$?

Comment: Also, what are $\alpha$ and $\beta$?  $\alpha$ had better be nonzero, if you're going to avoid a zero denominator in the first term.

Comment: @picakhu: i just want to find the suitable equation for related summation.

Comment: Oh, you mean a *solution/expression*? Thanks, that helps.

Comment: @leonbloy: yes, it doesn't matter if use $t$ or $xz$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: $\alpha, \beta $ just a constant value

Comment: @DimitrijeKostic: yes, $\alpha, \beta \neq 0$

Comment: It is not trivial. [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n%3D0+to+infty+(t^n%2F%28n*A%2BB%29))

Comment: I dont know why the link doesnt work. Copy and paste this. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n%3D0+to+infty+{t^n+%2F+%28nA%2BB%29}

Comment: @picakhu: thanks for introducing that software..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $x$ and $z$ only occur as a product, denote $w = x z$. We seek to evaluate
$ f(w) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{w^n}{\beta n + \alpha}$.

Notice that $\frac{w^n}{n \beta + \alpha} = \frac{1}{\beta} w^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}} \int w^{n - 1+ \frac{\alpha}{\beta}} \mathrm{d} w$. Therefore
$$
  f(w) = \frac{1}{\beta} w^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}} \int_0^w \frac{z^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}}{1-z} \mathrm{d} z + \frac{c}{\beta} w^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}
$$
The constant $c$ is determined by setting $\alpha = \beta$. Then, using the series, $f(w) = \frac{1}{\beta w} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{w^{n+1}}{n+1} = -\frac{1}{\beta w} \log(1-w)$.

So we get:
$$
  -\frac{1}{\beta w} \log(1-w) = \frac{1}{\beta w} \int_0^w \frac{1}{1-z} \mathrm{d} z + \frac{c}{\beta w}
$$ 
From where it follows that $c=0$. Therefore the sum admits the following integral representation:
$$
   f(w) = \frac{1}{\beta} w^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}} \int_0^w \frac{z^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}}{1-z} \mathrm{d} z = \frac{1}{\beta} \int_0^1 \frac{u^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}}{1-w u} \mathrm{d} u = \int_0^1 \frac{u^{\alpha-1}}{1- w u^\beta} \mathrm{d} u
$$
This integral define a special function, known as [Lerch zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function).

---

Actually the question from Didier Piau, made me realize that I missed a simpler route:
$$
 f(w) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{w^n}{\beta n +\alpha} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  w^n \int_0^1 u^{n \beta + \alpha-1} \mathrm{d} u  = \int_0^1 \frac{u^{\alpha-1}}{1-w u^\beta} \mathrm{d} u  
$$

Comment: The computation of $c$ is odd. All one knows is that for every $(\alpha,\beta)$ there is some $c_{\alpha,\beta}$ such that $f(w)$ is so and so, and you show that $c_{\alpha,\alpha}=0$ for every $\alpha$. Right. But this seems to give no information at all on $c_{\alpha,\beta}$ for $\alpha\ne\beta$.

Comment: @DidierPiau Yes, but I can justify $c_{\alpha,\beta} = 0$ _a-posteriori_, by rexpanding the integrand. I have expanded the answer. Of course, the integral representations in my post work for $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}>0$.

Comment: thanks all.. any other ways to find the expression instead of using Lerch zeta function?

Comment: @Norlyda Not for generic $\alpha$, $\beta$. Notice, though, that for $\alpha = \beta/2$, $f(w) = \frac{2}{\beta \sqrt{w}} \arctan(\sqrt{w})$.

Comment: @Sasha: my task is actually to form that summation in form of this expression,  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^n}{z^n}=\frac{1}{1-xz}$, maybe it is impossible,right?

Comment: The route to $c=0$ still seems wrong, except when $\alpha=\beta$.

Comment: @Sasha: please help me to solve [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87775/another-problem-of-solving-summation) too.. really need your guidance. Tqsm.

Answer (score 6):

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n\beta+\alpha}=
\frac1{\beta x^{\alpha/\beta}}\int\limits_0^{x}\frac{u^{\alpha/\beta}}{1-u}\frac{\mathrm du}u
$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{x^n}{z^n}}{n\beta + \alpha}$$

is expressible in terms of the [Lerch transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html):

$$\Phi(z,s,a)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{(a+k)^s}$$

Taking $s=1$ gives

$$\Phi(z,1,a)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{a+k}$$

after which

$$\begin{align*}\Phi(xz,1,a)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(xz)^k}{a+k}\\
\Phi(xz,1,\alpha/\beta)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(xz)^k}{\alpha/\beta+k}\\
\frac1{\beta}\Phi(xz,1,\alpha/\beta)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(xz)^k}{\alpha+\beta k}\end{align*}$$

and presto!